# how to search fields on database with date range on mysql codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, date-range

i've tried to create a search engine with date range filter but the whenever i type on my 'search_textbox' it does not include the date it only search the fields where it much the statement 'name' like '%a%';

```
if($search !=''):
        $added_query = "and date_created like '%".$search."%' or 
                                name like '%".$search."%' or
                                  alias like '%".$search."%' or
                                  designation like '%".$search."%' 
                                  ";
        else:
        $added_query ="";
        endif;
        $project_details = $this->db->query("SELECT *
                                 FROM ".$query."_man_power
                                  WHERE date_created BETWEEN '".$date_from."' AND '".$date_to."'
                                  ".$added_query."
                                order by date_created desc
                                  ");
            return $project_details;
```

Comment: Which input you are giving in your search text box for date?

Comment: $search = $this->input->post('search_textbox');

Comment: im trying to search something on my table while searching the fields ive already set my date_from and date_to but my query only searches the fields and it does not include my set date_from and date_to... how can i do it well?

Comment: As you are saying you have two different fields of date date_from & date_to, how you are getting and setting inputs for both fields? Are you trying to search in table by entering the date (like 2018/09/01)?

Comment: no, i am tryng to search by entering fields like name, designation, alias, amount with the the date range that i had set

Comment: ive set my date_from and date_to from my VIEW page to my jquery function to my controller... where my controller display ther output of my model... as indicated on top of my post

Comment: i mean i have 3 variables on my model that it is search, date_from and date_to

Comment: Why you added `date_created like '%".$search."%'` in your $added_query variable?

Comment: im also trying to search the date_created where only see whats on that date?

Comment: Sorry, but I am not getting your concern. Could you please explain little bit more.

Comment: ive tried to create a search engine that searches date_created, name,designation, alias and amount. but i want to add a date range filter on my search engine. but when i type a match or like values on my search engine my date range date_from and date_to does not filters the dates

Answer (score 0):

You probably are not formatting the dates in your where clause properly. See:
https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/sql_dates.asp

You want to make sure `$date_from` and `$date_to` look like the following depending on type:

```
$date_from = '2018-06-01 0:00:00';
$date_to = '2018-06-30 23:59:59';
```

You can inspect your query better to find the problem by viewing it.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$query."_man_power";
$sql .= " WHERE date_created BETWEEN '".$date_from."' AND '".$date_to."'".$added_query;
$sql .= " order by date_created desc";

var_dump($sql);

$project_details = $this->db->query($sql);
```

Comment: this is the last query of my model

Comment: SELECT * FROM EMJGC_man_power WHERE date_created BETWEEN '2018-09-01' AND '2018-10-01' and date_created like '%a%' or name like '%a%' or alias like '%a%' or designation like '%a%' order by date_created desc

Answer (score 0):

When combining these conditions, it is important to use parentheses so that the database knows what order to evaluate each condition.So group the AND,OR conditions with parenthesis like : -

```
if($search !=''):
    $added_query = "and ( 
        date_created like '%".$search."%' or 
        name like '%".$search."%' or
        alias like '%".$search."%' or
        designation like '%".$search."%' 
        )";
else:
  $added_query ="";
endif;
$project_details = $this->db->query("SELECT *
        FROM ".$query."_man_power
        WHERE date_created BETWEEN '".$date_from."' AND '"
       .$date_to."'".$added_query." order by date_created desc");
        return $project_details;`
```